# Render error Unknown Fragment Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Hello I am wondering how to clear a render error I am having with a fragment which is saying unknown fragment. I can seem to find what I did wrong to fix it. I have a recycleview in the fragment that is just a test to make sure that is working as well right now.

Here is the Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="jlfletcher.cpsc4367.ualr.edu.hw2.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentone"
        android:name="layout.FragmentOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Java of the fragment

```
package layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import jlfletcher.cpsc4367.ualr.edu.hw2.CPSClist;
import jlfletcher.cpsc4367.ualr.edu.hw2.R;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment 
{
    public void OnCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = 
       (RecyclerView)View.findViewById(R.id.Class_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        CPSClist textAdapter= new CPSClist();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(textAdapter);

        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringList.add("This");
        stringList.add("is");
        stringList.add("a");
        stringList.add("of");
        stringList.add("the");
        stringList.add("recycle");
        stringList.add("view");
        stringList.add("system");
        stringList.add("this");
        stringList.add("is");
        stringList.add("only");
        stringList.add("a");
        stringList.add("test.");

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(stringList);
        list.addAll(stringList);
        list.addAll(stringList);
        list.addAll(stringList);
        list.list(stringList);
        list.addAll(stringList);

        textAdapter.setItems(list);
    }
}
```

Thanks again for the help on this.

Comment: Can I see logcat for render error? and what is the unknown fragment?

Comment: On the logcat when I made it bigger it had a thing to pick which fragment, and when I did it worked, made me feel a bit stupid.

Comment: That's mean you need to take a rest a bit..